# XPath is not finding element

Tags: selenium, xpath

XPath I created:

```
.//*[@id='stepCongrats']/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/span
```

using this xPath I am getting message: NoSuchElementException

Below is my html code:

```
<div id="stepCongrats">
<div id="ancillary-congratulations"></div>
<div id="elephant"></div>
<div class="sect">
    <div class="s-header"></div>
    <div class="s-nav"></div>
    <div class="s-body">
        <div class="s-policyholder"></div>
        <div class="s-policyinfo">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <h6>
                        Policy number
                    </h6>
                    <span>
                        247-000-001-13
                    </span>
```

Comment: If you're using chrome, right click on the element and select "copy XPath", then paste it to the code.

Comment: @MarounMaroun when I copied xpath it is giving me same: //*[@id="stepCongrats"]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/span, but when I am running my scripts it says no element found.

Comment: This looks like a classic Selenium timing issue. The elements is probably not there yet when you try to find it. It may be created asynchronously. See http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits

Answer (score 4):

In XPath, elements in a list are numbered from 1, not 0. `div[2]` is the elephant, not the sect. Just increment the index:

```
.//*[@id='stepCongrats']/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/span
```

Comment: No luck doing the increments, I have changed the xpath to : .//*[@id='stepCongrats']/div[3]/div[4]/div[3]/ul/li[1]/span but still getting same nosuchelement exception

Comment: @user3464008: I'm sorry, I didn't check the other indices. Check the update (tested).

Answer (score 0):

```
//div[@id='stepCongrats']/div[3]/div[2]/ul/li/span
```

or

```
//dic[@class='s-policyinfo]/ul/li/span
```

Answer (score 0):

`//h6/span/` is the XPath or else you can use the FirePath addon for FireFox to get the perfect XPath